# SQL Previous date record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm writing a query which would bring back data for the most current and the previous month's data.

Here's the dates in the database and they could be different day's every month (not always posting on the 1st).  So, I need to pull the most current (max) (2017-07-03 and previous dates 2017-06-01)

```
filedate
2017-05-01
2017-06-01
2017-07-03
```

**Here's what I've tried:**

```
declare @filedate date = '2017-07-03'

select distinct max(filedate) filedate
from Table
where filedate = @filedate
order by filedate asc


select filedate
from Table
where filedate < (select min(@filedate) from Table)
group by filedate
```

**and the results:**

```
filedate (from the first query)
2017-07-03

filedate (from the second query)
2017-05-01
2017-06-01
```

Comment: It is unclear to me how you get the two earlier dates.  Are they from the beginning of the two previous months?

Comment: Yes, so currently there are only 3 dates in the table and it will keep growing.  I need to pull the max, which I can do, but the prior date is causing me problems.

Comment: Please add a few more records to the sample data and provide expected output (as opposed to what you getting now)

Comment: What is your expectation for prior date? Is it the 2nd date to the max or is is the max date for last month?

Comment: The expected output should be 2017-06-01 for the prior date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to `@CuriousKid.`..Here's what I did to make this work.

```
declare @filedate date = (select max(filedate) from Table)  --'2017-07-03'

select distinct top 1 filedate as PriorDate
from Table
where filedate <> @filedate
order by filedate desc
```

Comment: Hard codding a date is a bad idea. It will not work in a few days.

Comment: This code will go into an SSRS report, so it's only for testing purposes and then the logic will be changed within SSRS.  Not sure why I get downvoted for asking a very detailed question?  I guess if you don't know what the community expects you to know, then you get downvoted.

Comment: I changed the `@filedate` to pull the max filedate from the table, this way you will not have the hard coded value and should not give any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the magical query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 2 filedate
FROM TABLE
ORDER BY filedate DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

How about selecting the top 2? like this:

```
select top 2 filedate
from Table
order by filedate desc
```

Comment: I tried this and it pulls back both 2017-05-01 and 2017-06-01.  I only need the 2017-06-01 date as the prior date.

Comment: Try this query with TOP 1 ?

Comment: If I do the query with Top 1, then I get 2017-05-01

Comment: @BIReportGuy Are you _sure_ you're ordering by filedate **DESC**?

Comment: TRY adding **DESC** to your query in order by clause same as in the answer.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using `order by filedate desc`

Comment: If I do query just like above with the order by filedate desc, then I get the 2017-07-03 date twice.

Comment: Add **DISTINCT** to the query. `select distinct top 2 filedate
from Table
order by filedate desc`

Comment: @curisoukid  that did it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select max(filedate)from
(select '2017-05-01' as filedate union all
select '2017-06-01' union all
select '2017-04-10' union all
select '2017-07-03') as a where filedate<

(select max(filedate)from
(select '2017-05-01' as filedate union all
select '2017-06-01' union all
select '2017-04-10' union all
select '2017-07-03') as a limit 1)

union ALL

select max(filedate)from
(select '2017-05-01' as filedate union all
select '2017-06-01' union all
select '2017-04-10' union all
select '2017-07-03') as a
```

result:

```
2017-06-01
2017-07-03
```

You only have to replace the sample data as your table name like this:

```
select max(filedate)from
(select filedate from yourtable) as a where filedate<

(select max(filedate)from
(select filedate from yourtable) as a limit 1)

union ALL

select max(filedate)from
(select filedate from yourtable) as a
```